# Will all HTTP clients redirect GET requests when a server responds with a 301 or 302?

Tags: http, redirect, http-status-code-301, http-status-code-302

I have read through some relevant portions of the HTTP 1.0 and HTTP 1.1 specifications to try to ascertain whether all HTTP clients will perform the appropriate redirect when they receive a response of a 301 or 302 to a GET request.

Are there any HTTP clients that do not automatically follow the returned redirect in such an instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want to know this? What are you going to do with the answer, not using redirects if so?

The specs quite clearly state:

> [**6.4.  Redirection 3xx**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4)

> The 3xx (Redirection) class of status code indicates that further
> action needs to be taken by the user agent in order to fulfill the
> request.  If a Location header field (Section 7.1.2) is provided, the
> user agent **MAY** automatically redirect its request to the URI
> referenced by the Location field value, even if the specific status
> code is not understood.

So no, a client that does not automatically redirects, still adheres to the specs.

Comment: The question is to determine whether I might break clients if I modified my service to returned redirects rather than returning the content directly. The content in question is consumed by devices such like TVs with potentially non-standard http clients.